# C# REQUEST HANDLER ERROR System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, requesthandler

When i try to execute this function i get the error
"System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at server.mihail.credits.HandleRequest() in F:\Users\Mihail\Documents\new-sentients-2016\server\mihail\credits.cs:line 34
   at server.RequestHandler.HandleRequest(HttpListenerContext context) in F:\Users\Mihail\Documents\new-sentients-2016\server\RequestHandlers.cs:line 37
   at server.Program.ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context) in F:\Users\Mihail\Documents\new-sentients-2016\server\Program.cs:line 156
```

This is the function:
I try to execute it with parameters guid as my email address and parameter aid with the number one in it.

Please help me, i have been trying all day to fix it.

```
class credits : RequestHandler
{
    protected override void HandleRequest()
    {
        string status = "403";
        using (Database db = new Database())
        {
        NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Context.Request.Url.Query);
        MySqlCommand cmd = db.CreateQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE uuid=@uuid";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uuid", query["guid"]);
        object id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (id != null)
        {
        int amount = int.Parse(query["aid"]);
        cmd = db.CreateQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE stats SET credits = credits + @amount WHERE accId=@accId";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accId", (int) id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amount);
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result > 0)
                    status = "400";
                else
                    status = "500";
           }
            else
               status = "404";
        }
        byte[] res = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
             status);
        Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(res, 0, res.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is it throwing the exception on? I'm not going to count 'em :)

Comment: @LaneL you can if it is indeed a boxed int. There is no point guessing at what the problem is if the OP can't be bothered to tell us what line throws the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited information you have provided, it looks like the problem is with the line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accId", (int) id);`, as that is the only line with a cast.

Check the type of the `accounts.id` column in your database, I suspect it is not an `INT`, so you will need to change the cast (the type in the parentheses) to whatever type it is.  A `SMALLINT` is a `short` in C#, `BIGINT` is `long`, `TINYINT` is `byte` (or `sbyte`), and you'd need to look at the documentation to see what `MEDIUMINT` maps to, but its probably `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that i have (int) before id but it isn't needed so i only removed the (int) before ID.

So i can replace this line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accId", (int) id);
```

with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accId", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing which line is tossing this error.

I can see a cast happening from object to int with your id variable.

The following could show your problem

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ObjectToInt()
    {
        object a = 2;
        object b = "3";
        int aa = (int)a;
        int bb = (int)b; // this throws the same error
        var x = 1;
    }
```

Maybe make the int nullable with int? or see what the value of object really is.

Hope this helps.